# Error "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred" when trying update in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I'm trying to update entity I'm getting an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Recipe.Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Ingredient.RecipeId' on the other end.'

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(RecipeEditViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    var recipe = new Recipe()
    {
        Id = viewModel.Id,
        Name = viewModel.Name,
        AboutDish = viewModel.AboutDish,
        Ingredients = viewModel.Ingredients,
        Directions = viewModel.Directions
    };

    if (viewModel.File != null)
    {
        // upload file logic   
    }

    _context.Entry(recipe).State = EntityState.Modified; //**Error here**
    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Model classes:

```
//recipe.cs
public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Name, etc

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

// ingredient.cs
public class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Name, etc...

    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(RecipeId))]
    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
}
```

View model:

```
// RecipeEditViewModel.cs
public class RecipeEditViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Name, etc...

    public ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `ProxyCreationEnabled` set to `true`?

Comment: The value of `viewModel.Id`, when you make the POST is not an existing one. You could verify this by setting a breakpoint at `if (!ModelState.IsValid)` and triggering a POST. Then by inspecting the value of  `viewModel.Id` you would notice that this is not an existing one. I suspect that you don't include this value in the form you POST and the value it takes is the default 0 (as an `int`). Apparently there isn't any recipe with id.

Comment: Check the values of `Ingredient.RecipeId` (in `viewModel.Ingredients`) vs. `viewModel.id`.

Comment: @Christos I'm getting correct Id from POST. It was my first thought when I saw this error.

Comment: @GertArnold You have right, `Ingredient.RecipeId` is set to `0` but `viewModel.id = 16`. Is there proper way to fix it? I'm newbie in MVC and I don't want to get bad habits

Comment: Yes, basically it's better to `Add()` the ingredients to the `Recipe.Ingredients` after `recipe` has been attached to the context, but it may be a challenge to figure out which ingredient is new/modified/removed as compared to the original `Recipe.Ingredients` collection. Which EF version is this? In EF6 this isn't as trivial as it looks (and probably should be), in EF-core it's a bit easier.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm using EF6.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Recipe.Id and Ingredient.RecipeId has different values which causes

> 'A referential integrity constraint violation"

you need to fix your data.